# Add code inside a function load()

Tags: jquery

Hi I have the following function load()

```
$("#div").load("page.php", {
          prodctfilter: $("#producto").val() 

       });
```

I want to add the following code inside the load()

```
('#div a').click(function(e) {
("#div").on("click", "a:not(.minlink)", function ( e ) {
("#div").load($(this).attr("href"));
e.preventDefault();
}); 
});
```

and it is something like this

```
 $("#div").load("page.php", {
              prodctfilter: $("#producto").val() 
              ('#div a').click(function(e) {
              ("#div").on("click", "a:not(.minlink)", function ( e ) {
              ("#div").load($(this).attr("href"));
              e.preventDefault();
               });  
               });
               });
```

the problem is that the way I am showing the example does not work as it gives me error sintax

I want to achieve is that when running inside page load () will activate the other features that make the response of the links display within the tag div

the question is very easy, just I have not much knowledge and do not know how to do what I want with the code

Comment: show your html code ..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost close to the solution. Just consulting with the [jQuery.load documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/#load-url-data-completeresponseText--textStatus--XMLHttpRequest) will reach you to the destination.

For now , I have summarized the  solution for you:

```
$("#div").load("page.php",{
      prodctfilter: $("#producto").val() 
   },function(){
         ('#div a').click(function(e) {
           ("#div").on("click", "a:not(.minlink)", function ( e ) {
           ("#div").load($(this).attr("href"));
           e.preventDefault();
         });  
       });
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry but the code you sent me does not work inside function Load(), you could edit this to make it work?

Comment: You can;t add code inside load until you edit the source code of jquery :p . This callback function will run after successful completion of loading. If you can describe the scenario more precise probably we can find a way out

Comment: I want to achieve is that when running inside page load () will activate the other features that make the response of the links display within the tag div